# Invalid SAML AuthN Request

Tags: xml, xsd, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

By trying to set up an SSO connection (sp initiated) between my SP and an IDP using ADFS, I am not able to get an answer from the IDP. The problem is that this IDP is a black box and i do not have the hand on.

So doing some debugging I checked that my query was valid and well formated using [this](https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php) tool and got this message

> Invalid SAML AuthN Request. Not match the saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd

But their is no more details and even when I check [saml protocol schema](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd), I don't find where the problem is with this request :

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    ID="_2e674db5054e407c30af" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2019-05-10T09:39:52Z" 
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://my-sp.com/callback">
    <saml:Issuer 
        xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">sp_name
    </saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy 
        xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified" 
        AllowCreate="true">
    </samlp:NameIDPolicy>
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext 
        xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
        Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef 
            xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
        </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Did I missed a required field or is one value not well formated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use Validate XML with the XSD schema, tool. When I did this, I got:

`Line: 14 | Column: 0  --> Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}NameIDPolicy': Character content is not allowed, because the content type is empty.`

So, I've removed the tag `</samlp:NameIDPolicy>` and just closed your `NameIDPolicy` as bellow:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest 
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
ID="_2e674db5054e407c30af" 
Version="2.0" 
IssueInstant="2019-05-10T09:39:52Z" 
ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://my-sp.com/callback">
<saml:Issuer 
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">sp_name
</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:NameIDPolicy 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified" 
    AllowCreate="true" />
<samlp:RequestedAuthnContext 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    Comparison="exact">
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
    </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
</samlp:RequestedAuthnContext></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was not allowed to leave empty content. But now i jst got "Error parsing xml string", do you have any idea where does it can comes from ?

Comment: @PopHip sorry, my mistake, I forgot to paste the close tag `</samlp:AuthnRequest>`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ah right, issue was here ! Thanks the request is now valid